# Scala function toMap to SortedMap or TreeMap?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to return a SortedMap or TreeMap with the function toMap at the point 'A'? Or the point 'B' it's needed to comply this task?
 
A:

```
val list = List(5, 4, 3).map(i => i -> i ).toMap
println(list)
Map(5 -> 5, 4 -> 4, 3 -> 3)
```

B:

```
println(SortedMap[Int, Int]() ++ list)
Map(3 -> 3, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you could use the `to[Coll]` method. It fails here because of the arity of the type parameters:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

// error: SortedMap takes two type parameters, expected: one
val list = List(5, 4, 3).map(i => i -> i ).to[SortedMap]
```

But you can annotate the return type and use the `breakOut` import that provides the necessary builder factory for arbitrary collection types:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
val list: SortedMap[Int, Int] = List(5, 4, 3).map(i => i -> i)(breakOut)
```